# Check the last character of first element in string array is the same as last character of the next element

Tags: arrays, string, data-structures

Two strings can be chained if the first one ends with the same character the second one starts with.

Given the set of 'n' strings, how can we verify efficiently, whether they can be chained or not?

Write a java program for that code and also the order of the words should not be changed.

For example,
`a={"hi","ice","eye"}` should print `"yes"` as it follows the order and `a={"hi","eye","ice"}` should print `"no"`.

Comment: Your title question is asking how to determine if the last character of first element is same as last character of the next element. But your problem statement appears to be asking how to determine if the last character of the first element is the same as the *first* character of the next element. Which is it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and especially http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. We are not a "do my homework for me" service.